# SELECT COUNT(*) Thinks String parameter is an IEnumerable - Returns an Array? (CockroachDB C#)

Tags: c#, mysql, postgresql, npgsql, cockroachdb

I am working on migrating a project that used a MySQL DB over to CockroachDB. In this query, I'm simply trying to see if the username exists in the accounts table. When I run the same query in a CLI, it returns count 1.

I am trying to get this integer in my C# application, however I'm not quite understanding the issue with adding a parameter in my query. If my SELECT COUNT(*) query has a string parameter in it, it seems to think this string is an IEnumerable?

```
public bool accExists(string id, string userName)
{
    int totalCount = 0;

    using (var conn = new NpgsqlConnection(connstr.getConnStr(id)))
    {
        //SSL Connection Init
        conn.ProvideClientCertificatesCallback += ProvideClientCertificatesCallback;
        conn.UserCertificateValidationCallback += UserCertificateValidationCallback;

        conn.Open();

        // Check if Account Exists
        NpgsqlCommand accExists = new NpgsqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM accounts WHERE username LIKE @username", conn);
        accExists.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", userName);

        // Query Executions:
        totalCount = Convert.ToInt32(accExists.ExecuteScalar());
    }

    // Return Value
    switch (totalCount)
    {
        case 1: // Account Exists
            return true;

        case 0: // Account Does NOT Exist
            return false;

        default: // Protective Code - Shouldn't be hit
            addManageLog("SYSTEM", id, "MORE THAN ONE OF THE SAME USERNAME " + userName);
            return false;
    }
}
```

The exception caught is:

> System.NotSupportedException: 'Npgsql 3.x removed support for writing a parameter with an IEnumerable value, use .ToList()/.ToArray() instead'

**EDIT:** I have also now tried changing the parameter line to:

```
accExists.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Varchar, userName);
```

to explicitly define the parameter type as it seems to think this is an `IEnumerable` value. However, this returns the exception:

> The NpgsqlDbType 'Varchar' isn't present in your database.

The username column in my database is set as a VARCHAR(50).

Thank you for your help!

Comment: It sounds like the parameter given is not handled correctly rather than the return value. `AddWithValue` isn’t usually recommended, rather adding a parameter with specific type and setting the value. Does doing it that way change anything?

Comment: You need to use the correct form. `AddWithValue(“@username”, NpgsqlDbType.String, UserName)`. Your version just adds a parameter with the value of `MySqlDbType.String` and then changes it. Also don’t mix MySQL types here!

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Yes! I just realized I was using the MySQL type as I posted the comment. I tried specifying the parameter type as a varchar with `accExists.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Varchar, UserName);` This causes the exception: `'The NpgsqlDbType 'Varchar' isn't present in your database.` The username column is of the type varchar in the accounts table. The type string doesn't exist for NpgsqlType. Is there a different/better way to explicitly define the parameter type? Thank you!

Comment: This sounds like cockroachdb has something weird going on which isn’t really compatible. My knowledge ends here unfortunately.

Comment: No worries, thank you for trying!

Comment: I'm not sure your question title and body are aligned; in the title you're implying you're getting an array out. In the body, the db driver seems to be implying you're putting an array in (misunderstanding your string?). As a minor aside, you should follow c# convention that MethodNames/ProperrtyNames start with uppercase and variableNames start with lowercase. Writing your variables like that makes them look like properties; it's quite confusing for developers that follow convention

Comment: @CaiusJard Yes, thank you. As I am now understanding the issue better, the issue is indeed with the string parameter being recognized as an IEnumerable value. I have updated the title and explanation a bit.

Comment: In terms of what to do about your problem, I would probably clone the npgsql repo and then you can step into it with the debugger (or choose "break when thrown" and catch npgsql in the act of throwing this exception, and investigate why it came to the conclusion that you'd passed it an enumerable parameter that is no longer supported

Comment: (If there was a full staxktrace posted I probably could have read the code on my cellphone on GitHub and made a suggestion, as a halfway house to cloning it and searching for the exception throw. It will certainly be easier for you to clone, build and reference it on your project in order to repro the problem though. I'll keep looking/see if GitHub has a search to locate what code file this throw is comin from)

Comment: If you find that the exception is genuine in that e.g. There really has been some enumerable passed as a result of calling AddWithValue, investigate what conversion process AddWithValue might have performed on your value

Comment: https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/blob/191643e2f933eb308dea8345fa15ec42720c0666/src/Npgsql/TypeMapping/ConnectorTypeMapper.cs#L119 Is the class that looks at what you've passed. In your case whatever your username has been transformed into has bypassed the usual lookup (of which you'd imagine .net string was a mapped-to-pgsql type) and made it down to being considered as an enumerable. Definitely think that the fastest way to get an answer to this one would be to get to this point in a debugger if you can; it's really convoluted trying to read code to see what's in these mapping dictionaries

Comment: And the code that throws "isn't present in your database" is on line 85 of that same class- seems to be doing some lookup of the database capabilities and maintaining a dictionary of the supported types, so the solution might be as simple as using `Parameters.Add(new Parameter(...))` with whatever type cockroach does support for strings ?

Comment: @CaiusJard I attempted to add the parameter with the following: `        `NpgsqlCommand accExists = new NpgsqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM accounts WHERE username LIKE @username", conn);
                NpgsqlParameter p = new NpgsqlParameter("username", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Varchar);
                p.Value = userName;
                accExists.Parameters.Add(p);` This still throws the "isn't present in the database' exception. Looking at: https://www.npgsql.org/doc/types/basic.html it seems npgsql doesn't have a Varchar type that is recognized from a .Net string type.

Comment: I've also tried changing the username column type in cockroachdb to the TEXT type instead of Varchar, as this type is apparently recognized with a string type in .NET but this still throws the "TEXT isn't present in database" exception. I'll step through the npgsql repo locally tomorrow, and see if I can track down the issue better. Thank you for your help with the issue!